# Automating integration testing for a command-line application

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, integration-testing, expect

I have a set of command-line applications whose tests I'd like to automate. This is for testing an IaaS cloud setup, so the tests will invoke launching new virtual machine instances (e.g. euca-run-instances) and then making sure they can be logged into via ssh, and even running some simple apps on the remote machine.

Are there any frameworks out there that are designed to do this sort of testing? I know there are frameworks to make it easier to run unit tests, and I know of things like (p)expect  to interact with things like ssh, but I'm not aware of tools that live in the intersection of these two worlds.

Comment: The tag 'shell' is ambiguous, do you mean to do this in windows or Linux/Unix. Add tag for OS and shell name to get more eyes on your problem.

Comment: Tags added. Forgot that not everyone lives in Unix-land.

Comment: Why is expect not meeting your needs? I'd think that with exec, spawn and friends, you have all the command line power that's needed?

Comment: I agree with @thiton. Expect is really a good tool for automating command line interaction. 

You could invoke unit-testing from the command line and do different things based upon the outcome of the unit-tests.

That would combine the best of two worlds and hence intersect them. Of course this isn't an already set up specific framework for the task you mention, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to invoke is command line oriented? Look no further than bash. I am afraid there is no library that will make it more general than it is already.

You can even do remote testing:

```
$ ssh user@server /bin/false ; echo $?
1

$ ssh user@server /bin/true ; echo $?
0
```

That means you can write a script, upload it on the server, execute it remotely and use its exit code to determine success (0) or failure (1).

Of course that does not solve all your problem. The exact test strategy depends on your situation. Split your work to make your life easier.

- vm setup
- vm testing
- vm deployment (server specific stuff added here)
- deployed vm testing
- deployed vm cleanup (remove testing stuff)

Have a look at shunit and save yourself the trouble to write your own unit testing framework. I can't really expand on shunit though. I discovered it after writing my own tool.

Answer (score 2):

[Cli-unit](http://txt.fliglio.com/cli-unit/) tests for expected output given a cli usage and the test files are in markdown, so you can include them as documentation (e.g. in your readme file)

E.g. README.md

```
### test: echo foo should output "foo"
#### when: 
    echo foo
#### then: 
    foo
```

Then run it:

```
cli-unitw.sh README.md 
Pass (1/1 tests successful)
```

(read more about cli-unit [here](http://txt.fliglio.com/2015/01/cli-tests-and-docs-with-cli-unit/))

Answer (score 1):

I've had a bit of success testing integration of our LDAP system into client servers using pexpect and pyhton's unittest.

We wrote a wrapper class around pexepect's child pxssh, which is explicitly geared around ssh handeling. We wrote functions into the pxssh class that could not only trap the output, but would also return the value of $? after the command ended.

This gave us flexability when we moved to unittest. The tests where then able to be written so that we could test for a output criteria or even against return values.

We where able to unit test:

- successful logged in
- expected to fail login
- expected folders
- expected files
- presence of login banners

as a fallout to this work, we adapted the pxssh class to re-ip/resolver over 1000 linux hosts, which made the effort much easier for our building move. I am sorry I cant share more specifics of code as work owns it (although I'm hoping to get them to release it)

Answer (score 1):

[Cram](https://bitheap.org/cram/) seems to have this functionality.

Comment: They don't support Windows

Answer (score 0):

here is my tips:
you may use a central host and run "ssh user@host cmd" with ssh key file authorize
Thus, you can control your many hosts much more easily.